# Notifications are only shown when opening notifications center

Tags: macos, notifications, sonoma

I have the following Problem working with notifications in my new MacBook:

The notifications are only shown inside the notifications center (clicking on Date and time), but there is no popup of the notification shown. I therefore always have to check the notification center manually after I return to my MacBook, since the notification popup ist Not visible.

This happens for all applications. The problem occurs on my MacBook M3. It does not in my MacBook M1. Both machines run MacOs Sonoma 14.3.

I compared the settings in both machines and they are all the same.

Any ideas how I can get the popup to Show up in my new machine?